# Mongodb: increment a value in a nested array when filtering parent by id

Tags: mongodb

i have a bunch of documents like this.

```
{
    id: "5sdf898s79d898s9d8f798d8djdja",
    colors: [
        {color:"red", count: 0},
        {color:"blue", count: 0},
        {color:"green", count: 0},
        {color:"yellow", count: 0},
        {color:"brown", count: 0},
    ]
}
```

i need to be able to filer the documents by id and then increment a colors count inside the colors array.  I'm not sure how to go about traversing it.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using [updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/index.html#db-collection-updateone) - filter by the `id` and the color you want, and use the `$inc` operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as below

```
db.getCollection('test').update(
{'id':'5sdf898s79d898s9d8f798d8djdja', 'colors.color':"red"},
{$inc:{'colors.$.count':1}}
)
```

`'colors.$.count'` `$` is a positional operator. It selects the matching element's count.

`$inc` is an update operator. It is similar to `$set`.